# FreeBSD 9-RELEASE-p3, vlan over lagg trunk (bce)

Tags: freebsd, vlan

I have a Dell Server with 2 onboard bce(4) NICs. Those two are trunked together using LACP to lagg0 on a EX2200 Juniper Switch. Over lagg0 i have 2 vlans.

Everything works fine when i only have one vlan configured, as soon as i configure the second, i start having sshd broken pipe issues for connections going to the server.

Best example, when i ssh into that server, it works for like 30 seconds, after that it will freeze with a broken pipe.

As soon as i remove the 2nd vlan (or at least take the IP Address off it), it will work fine again.

I might also add that this only breaks on routed traffic, if the traffic is coming from the same subnet as the vlan, it's fine.

```
[root@fbsd9] ~ # ifconfig
bce0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=c01bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,VLAN_HWTSO,LINKSTATE>
    ether 00:1a:a0:05:c5:da
    inet6 fe80::21a:a0ff:fe05:c5da%bce0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
bce1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=c01bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,VLAN_HWTSO,LINKSTATE>
    ether 00:1a:a0:05:c5:da
    inet6 fe80::21a:a0ff:fe05:c5d8%bce1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2 
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
lagg0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=c01bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,VLAN_HWTSO,LINKSTATE>
    ether 00:1a:a0:05:c5:da
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
    laggproto lacp
    laggport: bce1 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
    laggport: bce0 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
vlan4094: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=103<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4>
    ether 00:1a:a0:05:c5:da
    inet6 fe80::21a:a0ff:fe05:c5da%vlan4094 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    inet 172.16.1.197 netmask 0xffffffc0 broadcast 172.16.1.255
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
    vlan: 4094 parent interface: lagg0
vlan4093: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=103<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4>
    ether 00:1a:a0:05:c5:da
    inet6 fe80::21a:a0ff:fe05:c5da%vlan4093 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    inet 172.16.2.19 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.2.255
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
    vlan: 4093 parent interface: lagg0
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself,

the issue was that my junos router infront of the EX2200 had issues with assigning the MAC-addr of the lagg0 (and therefore the vlan*) to the right VLAN. I'll simply use a dedicated ethernet card to do routed services like ssh and stuff.

this way customers can connect to the server from within their vlans while i still have outbound/routed connectivity on the mgmt interface.

best regards